# all files on WebDav resource are write protected

Tags: pantheon-files, files, release-hera, webdav

I successfully connected my webdav cloud storage in elementary OS files manager. But if I copy for example my passwort database from home directory to the webdav directory, my passwort manager can't save anymore the database. I compared in the properties tab the permissions. In the home directory I'm the owner and have read and write permissions. If I copy the same file to my webdav resource I loose all permissions and I'm not anymore the owner of the file. 
I don't understand how this is possible that I can write the file to the webdav server but can't modifiy it anymore afterwards.

I search through the web but don't find any solution until now.
Any ideas / hints?

Comment: I have recreated the problem on another laptop also using elementaryOS and the problem can be reproduced there as well. I have done the same on Ubuntu Budgie and the webdav resource is also write-protected.

Comment: Just for clarification, I can copy files on the webdav resource, I can delete files on the webdav resource. But if I open an copyed file from my webdav resource, every app tells me the file is write protected?!?